# Bound on a $\chi^2$-type quantity

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions

Suppose $p,q\in([0,1]^{n})^k$ are two vectors such that, for every $1\leq \ell\leq k$, 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n p_{\ell,j} = \sum_{j=1}^n q_{\ell,j} = 1
$$
that is, for every fixed $\ell$, $(p_{\ell,j})_{1\leq j\leq n}$ and $(q_{\ell,j})_{1\leq j\leq n}$ are probability distributions. I want to prove the inequality
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{j'=1}^n \frac{\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})(p_{\ell,j'}-q_{\ell,j'})\right)^2}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j'}+q_{\ell,j'})}
\lesssim n\, \tag{$\dagger$}.
$$
Note that by Cauchy-Schwarz, one can get
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{j'=1}^n \frac{\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})(p_{\ell,j'}-q_{\ell,j'})\right)^2}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j'}+q_{\ell,j'})}
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{j'=1}^n \frac{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})^2\sum_{\ell=1}^k(p_{\ell,j'}-q_{\ell,j'})^2}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j'}+q_{\ell,j'})}\\
&= \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})^2}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})} \right)^2\\ 
&\leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \max_{\ell}\lvert p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j}\rvert \frac{\sum_{\ell=1}^k \lvert p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j}\rvert}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})} \right)^2\\ 
& \leq n^2
\end{align}$$
however this is only quadratic in $n$, while my goal is linear. I know how to prove it assuming the distributions are "trivial" (point masses), i.e., when $p,q\in(\{0,1\}^{n})^k$. This was enough for my application, but I feel that $(\dagger)$ should still hold for arbitrary distributions.

Comment: Could you also post the proof for the case of point mass? Maybe it could be generalized.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Oops, just saw that. I'll try when I get access to my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove more: if $v_i$ ($i=1,\dots,n$) are vectors in a Hilbert space with pairwise non-negative scalar products and $V=\sum_iv_i$, then
$$
\sum_{i,j}\frac{\langle v_i,v_j\rangle^2}{\langle v_i,V\rangle\langle v_j,V\rangle}\le \sum_{i,j}\frac{\langle v_i,v_j\rangle}{\langle v_i,V\rangle}=n\,.
$$
To derive your inequality, just consider $v_i=(p_{\ell,i}+q_{\ell,i})_{\ell=1}^k$ and replace $-$ by $+$ in the numerator. You'll get the bound of $4n$ (because $V=(2,2,\dots,2)$ instead of $(1,1,\dots, 1)$ you have in the denominator).

Comment: Looks interesting... how to prove this generalization (do you have a proof, or a reference -- or is it obvious?)

Comment: @ClementC.  I thought the inequality was obvious ($\langle v_j,V\rangle\ge \langle v_j, v_i\rangle$) and the identity is obvious by doing the summation over $j$ first.

Comment: Indeed, it is (obvious).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p_{\ell,j}q_{\ell,j}\geqslant 0$ hence 
$$\frac{(p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})^2}{\sum_{\ell'=1}^k (p_{\ell',j}+q_{\ell',j})}\leqslant \frac{ p_{\ell,j}^2+q_{\ell,j}^2}{\sum_{\ell'=1}^k (p_{\ell',j}+q_{\ell',j})} \leqslant p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j} . $$
It follows that 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}-q_{\ell,j})^2}{\sum_{\ell=1}^k (p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j})}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^k\left(p_{\ell,j}+q_{\ell,j}\right)  =2k.  $$

Comment: While that's definitely correct, I want to bound the thing by $O(n)$, not $k$. (In my application, typically $n\ll k$).